# Does the Groomed to Rule lifestyle only get applied to children born after I take the perk?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

The Groomed to Rule perk gives all of my children 1-3 skill points. One thing I'm not sure of from the text is if this is applied to all of my children, or only to those born after I take the perk. If it's only to those born after I take the perk it's fairly useless to me, since I already have quite a few children, so I'd rather not waste the perk point on it.

[image]

Is groomed to rule applied to all children, or just to those born after I unlock  the perk?

Comment: I specifically avoided this tree since I wasn't sure about this, but I was eventually forced to take it anyway, so figured I should  share this for anyone else wondering the same.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this is _supposed_ to work, but I have found after taking it that I will occasionally get popups with the "Groomed to Rule" heading announcing that some child or another has received a skill boost. So it seems to occasionally deliver more skill point boosts _after_ you take it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was eventually forced to unlock this perk to continue down the lifestyle tree, so I can confirm that this perk is immediately applied to **all living children.** Additionally, the perk has a chance to retrigger multiple times throughout your children's life (although I'm not sure what triggers is).

Based on the reading of the perk and my own experience, every time this perk triggers the child gets 1 random skill point, and  the perk can trigger a total of 3 times (including the initial trigger).

Comment: Bonus: Reset your perks, then trigger it again just before you die!